# Better way to create a new ojbect array from old

Tags: javascript

I have been in c# for too long. I am just jumping into ES6 and know there is a better way to do this. I want to avoid arguments about what way is better than another. I am looking for a common way that is more suited for es6 and not just me translating c# to js.

```
const dbImageItems = [
{
   _id: 17581,
   key: "F97E9FEF-D4A7-408C-88BF-BE033F6F3169",
   reqStatus: "SUCCESS",
   errorMsg: "",
   requestDt: "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
},
{
   _id: 17580,
   key: "C744520A-57CD-461F-B03E-8CC4F8D97CD4",
   reqStatus: "ERROR",
   errorMsg: "An error occured",
   requestDt: "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
}]

function ImageItem(id, guid, status, errMsg) {
   this.id = id;
   this.guid = guid;
   this.status = status;
   this.errMsg = errMsg;
}

export function getImageItems() {
  let imageItems = [];
  dbImageItems.forEach(function(value) {
    const item = new ImageItem(
      value._id,
      value.key,
      value.reqStatus,
      value.errorMsg
    );
    imageItems.push(item);
  });
  return imageItems;
}
```

The reason that I am doing this is we have a legacy app and a new app. The data returned from the old and new APIs are different.

I want to unify the two by creating a common object so very little has to change when I switch from the old data API format to the new format.

Note: I am skipping the requestDt field, and I am renaming a couple other fields.

I have read about spreads and many other cool functionality from js but I am stuck in the C# mind frame.

-Gina

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you have, in my opinion.

Comment: This question might be better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Use `map` instead of `forEach` + `push` + `[]`

Comment: What's the point of the `ImageItem` constructor? Is this just a simplified code, or do these instances really have no methods? If you don't need instances for anything, just use an object literal in `getImageItems`.

Comment: @Ivar Thanks, I had not know about Code Review. I love it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one line using arrow function, map instead of forEach in order to not mutate an empty array, and an object spread of the values:

```
 const getImageItems = () => dbImageItems.map(obj => new ImageItem(obj._id, obj.key, obj.reqStatus, obj.errMsg))
```

Comment: Is it really safe to rely on the order of `Object.values(obj)`?

Comment: In the case of keys of type string, order should be guaranteed in chronological order as of ES2015, but agree that it is safer to be explicit: `const getImageItems = () => dbImageItems.map(obj => new ImageItem(obj._id, obj.key, obj.reqStatus, obj.errMsg)`.

Comment: @DanielVarela for some reason I am getting an empty array.

Comment: @DanielVarela I removed "() => " and it works. Please update your answer with the explicit code and fix.

Comment: You don't want getImageItems to be a function? Take a look at https://repl.it/repls/FreeMindlessRange, both functions return the same result using explicit parameters like in the comment above.

Comment: @DanielVarela ahhh, I put the code inside "export function getImageItems()"